# Django + sendmail + postfix

Tags: postfix, sendmail, django

I've a Linode server and I've just deployed my application.

A feature of my application is to send email notifications to users when an event is triggered. I want only send mail from my server, for receive I use Google Apps.

I've installed postfix:
`apt-get install postfix`

and as [Linode guide](http://library.linode.com/using-linux/administration-basics#sph_sending-email-from-your-server) says, I should send email from my application. But it doesn't work.

I've forgotten some configuration or other things to do for sending email?

This in my `settings.py`:

```
EMAIL_HOST: 'localhost'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Might be better to use gmail for that.. you won't get tagged with spammy emails on some hosts

http://www.mangoorange.com/2008/09/15/sending-email-via-gmail-in-django/

Comment: It might be better. But how about the speed? If I send with gmail isn't more slow than if I send from my server?

Comment: easy.. offload the sending of email using like django-tasks or something

Comment: Yeah, I send email asynchronously. Works well.

Answer (score 0):

I am not familiar with linode, but a number of distributions ship with the service disabled.  Is the postfix master actually listening on either port 25 or 587?

Answer (score 0):

Although sendmail and not postfix oriented, it may help: [mail hosted at Google, web server elsewhere](http://blog.postmaster.gr/2011/03/14/mail-hosted-at-google-web-server-elsewhere/).